# Level shifter breaks down (repeatedly)

Tags: esp32, level-shifting, logic-level

I created a Dometic Airco thermostat using esphome on an esp chip. The Dometic is expecting 5V on the serial control line, not the 3.3V coming from the esp.

So I implemented a simple circuit using a level shifter. See image. It works fine for a while and something happens and the level shifter fails. I replaced the level shifter but again it starts failing after a few days.

I’m not sure how to troubleshoot or what to do about this issue. Any help or advice in pointing me in the right direction would be great. [image]

Comment: What is a "traco"?

Comment: What level shifter?? Part no? Model no.? IC part no?

Comment: It is unknow what level shifter that and if it is suitable for that application.

Comment: Level shifter: Anmbest 5PCS 4 Chanels High Speed Bi-Directional 3.3V-5V Logic Level Converter for Arduino Raspberry Pi Electronic Development https://a.co/d/hwwSwv3

Comment: Traco is a DC-DC converter. Part numbers: TSR2-2450 and TSR2-2433

Comment: oh I know those level shifters. They should work okay. I don't see what would cause one to break unless maybe you have outputs on both sides, instead of one input and one output.

Comment: The Dometic airco is a black box and the comms protocol between it and its thermostat is not published. So I used a salaea logic analyzer to sniff the control signals and then mimicked them on the esp. I don’t know if the Dometic unit is sending something back to the thermostat that might be causing an issue. But the level shifter is bidirectional so even if that is the case, it shouldn’t cause the shifter to break I would think.

Comment: No level shifter data sheet = no clues = typical amazon/ebay/bang-bad/ali-express purchase = no defined manufacturing quality system = don't buy unless desperate and don't have high hopes.

Comment: It looks identical to this (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009), which is based on the Fairchild BSS138 (data sheet: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/BSS138.pdf)

Comment: Ok, so I got the 'proper' level shifter from Sparkfun mentioned above. Looks identical. Unfortunately, behaves identical too. It failed after a few weeks. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this or come up with a different solution. I checked voltage levels of the Tracos. They are correct. I checked the 3.3V control signal coming from the ESP chip. It is correct as well. The 12V input is stabilized so that shouldn't be an issue either.